# How to increment counter on button click using Django

Tags: python, html, django

New to Django, and I'm stuck on a problem. I have several buttons on a page, each is an instance of a simple Color object I created. The object has attributes of 'name'(string),'hex'(string), and 'count'(integer). I want to be able to keep track of how many times each button is pressed; so, for example, if someone presses the button associated with 'Red,' it will Post to the database that the 'count' attribute for Red should increment by 1.

This is basically how the 'vote' function works in the app they show in the Django documentation, but I cannot figure out how to apply it to my program, even though mine is simpler. Any advice is appreciated. Please let me know if I've posted enough code to determine the issue.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from .models import Color

### function in question ###
def detail(request, colorname):
    bodybg = colorname
    colorslist =  Color.objects.all()
    colorcount = 0
    for color in colorslist:
        if colorname == color.hex:
            colorcount = color.count
    colorCounterObj = get_object_or_404(Color, pk=colorcount)
    selected_color = colorCounterObj.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice']) 
    selected_color.count += 1 
    selected_color.save() 
    context = {
        'bodybg' : bodybg,
        'colorslist' : colorslist,
        'colorcount' : colorcount,
    }
    template = loader.get_template('colortime/detail.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

```html
<!-- HTML on my index page, where the buttons are. Makes a list of buttons in different colors, that works just fine. Not sure if my 'formaction' is worded properly or really even functional -->
<body>
<center>
{% if colorslist %}
    <ul>
    {% for color in colorslist %}
        <li ><h3 class='button' style='background-color:{{ color.hex }};' formaction="{% url 'colortime:detail' color %}" method="post" name='choice'><a href="/color/{{ color.hex }}/">{{ color.name }}</a></h3></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}"
    <p>No colors here.</p>
{% endif %}
</center>
</body>
```

Right now the error I'm getting is:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/color/0000FF/
Raised by:  colortime.views.detail
No Color matches the given query.

The url varies slightly based on which button I press but they all do this.

Edit: Models.py and Urls.py below

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'colortime'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:colorname>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

```py
from django.db import models
from django import forms
# Create your models here.
class Color(models.Model):
    hex = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: i think this error happen because `colorCounterObj = get_object_or_404(Color, pk=colorcount)` raise exception. update your question with  `models.py` and `urls.py` .

Comment: I am reaffirming @mehdi's comment. Please include your `models.py` and `urls.py`.